# Issue with TextArea height

Tags: java, javafx-8

I had posted the same question [in oracle javafx forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3582196) too but haven't got a response. So trying my luck here.

I have a requirement where in the content of the text area is dynamically populated from the database. I am able to successfully retrieve and display the data on the text area.

However when the content is too large, I am not able to dynamically set the height of the text area. When I try to display the same as a label, the display is flawless, dynamically sets the height as per the content. So, I tried to create a label, with same content and dynamically bind the height to the preferred height as below, but it doesn't work.

```
// Generate User Note Description  
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();  
Label text = new Label();  

// SETTING THE TEXT TO A LABEL TO RETRIEVE THE HEIGHT   
text.setText(usrNotes.getNote().trim());  

// ALWAYS DISPLAYS 0.0  
System.out.println("height::"+text.getHeight());  

if (isMyNote) {  
   // ALWAYS SETS TO THE MINIMUM HEIGHT OF 60.0  
   textArea.setText(usrNotes.getNote().trim());  
   textArea.setPrefWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth() - 500.0);  
   textArea.setWrapText(true);  
   textArea.setMinHeight(60.0);  

   // WITHOUT THIS BINDING, DISPLAYS LOT OF EXTRA SPACE AFTER THE TEXT  
   textArea.prefHeightProperty().bind(text.heightProperty());  
   textArea.setStyle("-fx-padding:0 5 2 1; -fx-font-size: 1.1em;-fx-background-color:white");  
} else if (!isMyNote) {  

   // THIS IS PERFECT, AS EXPECTED SETS THE HEIGHT DYNAMICALLY  
   text.setText(usrNotes.getNote().trim());  
   text.setStyle("-fx-padding:0 5 2 1;");  
   text.setStyle("-fx-border-color: white;-fx-font-size: 1.1em;-fx-background-color:#F5F5F5;");  
   text.setWrapText(true);  
   text.setPrefWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth() - 500.0);  
   text.setMinHeight(60.0);  
}
```

I would highly appreciate if someone can provide a hint on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks -SV

Answer (score 1):

The reason `text.getHeight()` returns 0, (and therefore have to bind to `text.heightProperty()`) is because the height isn't calculated when the component is constructed.  It is calculated when the component is rendered to the screen.

If you want to calculate a height ahead of time, I believe you will have to use something like FontMetrics (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) to calculate the width and line height of your string, break up the string into tokens to figure out where line breaks will fall (based on your width), and then figure out how many lines you will need (and therefore, how high your TextArea needs to be).